# Why do these SVG rotations not align?

Tags: svg

I've got a path and some text that both have the same transform applied (to rotate them). And yet the angle of the text does not match the angle of the path. I can't figure out why?

```html
    <svg width="600" height="600">
        <path transform="matrix(0.9642053928037905 0.2651564830210419 -0.2651564830210419 0.9642053928037905 121.55313086036932 -84.43174667230568)" style="fill: none;stroke: rgb(0, 0, 0)" d=" M 295.5198888569934,350.25614953846303 L 470.04106495447945,398.2494729652716 L 451.4801111430065,465.74385046153697 L 276.9589350455205,417.75052703472835 Z "></path>

        <text transform="matrix(0.9642053928037905 0.2651564830210419 -0.2651564830210419 0.9642053928037905 121.55313086036932 -84.43174667230568)" x="282.9999999999999" y="390" style="font-family: Arial;font-size: 12;fill: rgb(0, 0, 0);stroke: none">Some Rotated Text</text>
    </svg>
```

Thanks for any enlightenment!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is because the rectangle isn't axis aligned in the first place.

If you remove the transforms from both elements you will see what I mean.

```html
<svg width="600" height="600">
    <path style="fill: none;stroke: rgb(0, 0, 0)" d=" M 295.5198888569934,350.25614953846303 L 470.04106495447945,398.2494729652716 L 451.4801111430065,465.74385046153697 L 276.9589350455205,417.75052703472835 Z "></path>

    <text x="282.9999999999999" y="390" style="font-family: Arial;font-size: 12;fill: rgb(0, 0, 0);stroke: none">Some Rotated Text</text>
</svg>
```

Comment: Yep, thanks - the path has been transformed twice - the first time to the actual points themselves. Now I have to find where :)

Answer (score 0):

The coordinate system for the matrix varies with difference in the size and position(i.e. from one SVG element to another)

You can use [**textPath**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/textPath) to bind the text with the path  and adjust the position using [**translate**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/transform).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <h1>SVG Rotation Weirdness</h1>

  <svg height="600" width="600">
    <path id="textPathShape" transform="matrix(0.9642053928037905 0.2651564830210419 -0.2651564830210419 0.9642053928037905 121.55313086036932 -84.43174667230568)" style="fill: none;stroke: rgb(0, 0, 0)" d=" M 295.5198888569934,350.25614953846303 L 470.04106495447945,398.2494729652716 L 451.4801111430065,465.74385046153697 L 276.9589350455205,417.75052703472835 Z "></path>
    <text style="font-family: Arial;font-size: 12;fill: rgb(0, 0, 0);stroke: none" transform="translate(14 54)">
      <textPath xlink:href="#textPathShape">Rotated Text</textPath>
    </text>
  </svg>

</body>

</html>
```